# cannot get subscribers email to mailchimp2.0

Tags: php, mailchimp

this seems pretty straightforward but i just can't get mailchimp to get the emails. I have a checkbox and all I want to do is say, if check then subscribe. 
I get an error 500 and I have no idea where to go with this.

```
 <?php echo CHtml::CheckBox('[subscribe]',true, array ( 'value'=>'yes',)); ?>


if ( $_POST['subscribe'])
    {
    Yii::import('application.vendors.mailchimp');
    $mailchimp = new Mailchimp(Yii::app()->params['mailchimp']['key']);
    $listId = '*******';
    $email = array(
        'email' => trim($_POST['User']['email']));
    $subscriber = $mailchimp->list->subscribe(
        $listId,
        $email,
        $merge_vars=null, 
        false,
        false
        );
    }
```

Comment: are you sure the string is 'subscribe'? Try checking the string before doing the comparison.

Comment: hmm well now it's giving me `Call to a member function subscribe() on a non-object`